# ¿Cómo se escriben las URLs complejas en Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Con los cambios de Django 1.8 y 1.9 me pierdo con las URLs.

En Django 1.6.5 tenía:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),

    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page':'login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^cambiar-pass/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name':'cambiar-pass.html', 'post_change_redirect':'login'}, name='cambiar_pass'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Ahora tengo la primera parte bien:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='publico/index.html'), name='home'), ...
```

Pero no se cómo van las otras líneas que he escrito, puesto que tenían argumentos en la versión 1.6.5

No me sale error sino warning:

````
RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got django.contrib.auth.views.password_change). Pass the callable instead.
url(r'^cambiar-pass/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name':'cambiar-pass.html', 'post_change_redirect':'login'}, name='cambiar_pass'),```
````

Comment: El warning tiene más que ver con tu template que con tu urls.py, si tienes algun argumento del tipo app.view.algo cambialo por el "algo" que pusiste en name="algo" en tu urls.py Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es solo una advertencia para que te vayas acostumbrando al cambio que viene, lo que te dice es que a partir de `Django 1.10` ya no podrás usar el nombre de las vistas como texto en el parámetro de la función `url()`, es decir, tendrás que cambiar esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'login.html'}, name='login'),
    # ...
]
```

Por esto:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name':'login.html'}, name='login'),
    # ...
]
```

### Nota:

Esto no tiene que ver con que las vistas sean basadas en funciones (FBV) o basadas en clases (CBV), aplica para ambos casos, no importa cual de ellas uses:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^foo/$', views.foo, name='foo'),
    # ...
]
```

O:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^foo/$', FooView.as_view(), name='foo'),
    # ...
]
```

Comment: Yo no entiendo bien por qué se hizo el cambio, pero me parece bastante bien que se organicen de mejor manera, se ve más ordenado.

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué error te manda? lo único que por el momento le pondría seria una , "coma" después de `.html`

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'login.html',}, name='login'),
```

saludos

Comment: Obsoleto, deprecated significa obsoleto, despreciado, depreciado.